# Send an email when adding a new user on Sakai

Tags: java, email, sakai

I want an email to be sent to a new user when they login to Sakai. I searched and found a property that I can add on sakai.properties called notifyNewUserEmail. I set it to true, but upon adding a new user using admin account from the Users tool, the email is still not sent to new user's email.

Is there another config I need to do? How do I enable this?

Comment: Is your Sakai setup to send email and do other email notification work? [link](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/DOC/Sakai+Admin+Guide+-+Email+Configuration) It looks like this property should be the one, though it won't send emails when a user creates their own account. If you set the property **smtpDebug@org.sakaiproject.email.api.EmailService=true** you should see emails written to the log.

Comment: All other notifications that send emails work. And yes, I know that property will print to log, but there is no email being printed to log either when creating a new account.